# 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python

[image: Table]
[image: Error]

I am trying to build a SNS plot by grouping the products(P5PN). But it is throwing an error "'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'shape'"

Answer (score 1):

Following the documentation for the [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method, there are a couple ways you could fix this. The way I'd recommend is to explicitly specify the grouping column using the `by` parameter (although you don't need to), and then providing an aggregation function (looks like you want the `mean`). Any of these will work:

```py
# Option 1
New.groupby(['P5PN']).mean()

# Option 2
New.groupby('P5PN').mean()

# Option 3
New.groupby(by=['P5PN']).mean()
```

The issue here is that while you are specifying a grouping column, you are not telling pandas how to aggregate the measures in the other columns of your data.

Note: you might want to update the title of your question to "'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'shape'" to match the actual error you're getting.